# Flutter - Json Serializing is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have encountered an issue passing data from services to models. The model is supposed to get the json from service, which fetched the data from API, and json converting it in model. But after the data passed into model, the Map toJson didn't process. 
I have tried it in many ways, but the result is still the same.

#### goals_view_service.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:requests/requests.dart';


// goal_data={
  //        [
//         'goal_name': savings_goal[1],
//         'amount': savings_goal[2],
//         'duration': savings_goal[3],
//       ]
//          }

class GoalViewServices{

  // List<GoalsModel> _goals;
  var goals = List<GoalsModel>();

   Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _getGoals() async {
      Response request;
      try {
        request = await Requests.get(
          url + '/savings_goal_display',
          headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
          // TODO: when having true ssl certificate, change verify to true.
          // verify: false,
          timeoutSeconds: 20,
        );
      } catch (e) {
        return {"result": "Connection Error: $e"};
      }
      if (!request.hasError) {
        try {
          return request.json() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        } catch (e) {
          return {"result": "$e"};
        }
      } else {
        return {"result": "Unknown Request Error"};
      }
  }


  Future<List<GoalsModel>> renewDataForView() async {
    var dic = await _getGoals();
    // var goals = List<GoalsModel>();
    if (dic != null) {
      // print(dic);
      // final savingsGoalsDic = dic['saving_goals'];
      final savingsGoalsDicArray = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(dic['savings_goals'] ?? {}) ?? [];
      // final savingsGoalsDicArray = (dic['savings_goals'] ?? {}) ?? [];
      print('savingsGoalsDic__: $savingsGoalsDicArray');
      for (final aData in savingsGoalsDicArray) {
          // print(aData);
          // Map json = jsonDecode(aData);
          // var title = aData["goal_name"];
          // var totalAmount = aData["amount"];
          // var durations = aData["duration"];
          goals.add(GoalsModel.fromJson(aData));
        }
    }
    // print(goals);
    return goals;
  }

}
```

#### goals_model.dart

```
class GoalsModel {
  String title;
  String imagePath;
  int totalAmount;
  int durations;

  GoalsModel({this.title,this.totalAmount,this.durations});

  // final Map<String, String> goalsImage = {
  //   "Housing": "assets/images/housing.jpg",
  //   "Car": "assets/images/car.jpg",
  //   "Retirement": "assets/images/retirement.jpg",
  //   "Shopping": "assets/images/shopping.jpg",
  //   "Travel": "assets/images/travel.jpg",
  //   "Wedding": "assets/images/wedding.jpg",
  //   "Study": "assets/images/study.jpg"
  // };

  GoalsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    // print(json);
    title = json["goal_name"] as String;
    // print(this.title);
    totalAmount = json["amount"] as int;
    // print(this.totalAmount);
    durations = json["duration"] as int;
    // print(this.durations);
    imagePath = "assets/images/study.jpg";
    // var data = _toJson(this.title,this.imagePath,this.totalAmount,this.durations);    

    // if (this.title == goals.keys){
    //     this.imagePath = goals.values;
    // }
  }

  // GoalsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  //     : title = json["goal_name"],
  //       totalAmount = json["amount"],
  //       durations = json["duration"],
  //        imagePath = "assets/images/study.jpg";

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson () =>{
    'title' : title,
    'imagePath' :imagePath,
    'totalAmount' : totalAmount,
    'durations': durations,

  };

}
```

#### Goals_viewmodels.dart

```
class GoalsViewModel extends BaseModel {
    GoalViewServices _goalViewServices=locator<GoalViewServices>();

    List<GoalsModel> goalList;

    Future<List<GoalsModel>> getGoals() async {
    setState(ViewState.Busy);
    goalList = await _goalViewServices.renewDataForView();
    print(goalList);
    setState(ViewState.Idle);
    return goalList;
  }

}
```

#### Goals Dictionary

```
savingsGoalsDic__: [{amount: 123, duration: 3, goal_name: Car}, {amount: 123, duration: 2, goal_name: Housing}, {amount: 0, duration: 5, goal_name: Retirement}, {amount: 0, duration: 2, goal_name: Shopping}, {amount: 0, duration: 2, goal_name: Travel}, {amount: 12, duration: 3, goal_name: Wedding}]
```

#### Result from Goals_model

```
[Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel', Instance of 'GoalsModel']
```

Comment: The only possible call of `toJson()` in your code is commented out and starts with a `_`. Try to uncomment the line and replace `_toJson()` with `toJson()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: `_getGoals()` need to return `json.decode(response.body);` for `Map<String, dynamic>`

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _getGoals() async {
    String jsonString = '''
    ...
    ''';
    http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);

    return json.decode(response.body);
```

Step 2: `renewDataForView()` can use `Payload.fromJson` see definition in full code

```
Future<List<GoalsModel>> renewDataForView() async {
    var dic = await _getGoals();
    Payload payload;
    if (dic != null) {
      payload = Payload.fromJson(dic);
    }
    // print(goals);
    return payload.savingsGoalsDic;
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  Payload({
    this.savingsGoalsDic,
  });

  List<GoalsModel> savingsGoalsDic;

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        savingsGoalsDic: List<GoalsModel>.from(
            json["savingsGoalsDic__"].map((x) => GoalsModel.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "savingsGoalsDic__":
            List<dynamic>.from(savingsGoalsDic.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class GoalsModel {
  GoalsModel({
    this.totalAmount,
    this.durations,
    this.title,
  });

  int totalAmount;
  int durations;
  String title;

  factory GoalsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GoalsModel(
        totalAmount: json["amount"],
        durations: json["duration"],
        title: json["goal_name"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "amount": totalAmount,
        "duration": durations,
        "goal_name": title,
      };
}

class GoalViewServices {
  // List<GoalsModel> _goals;
  var goals = List<GoalsModel>();

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _getGoals() async {
    String jsonString = '''
    {"savingsGoalsDic__": [{"amount": 123, "duration": 3, "goal_name": "Car"}, {"amount": 123, "duration": 2, "goal_name": "Housing"}, {"amount": 0, "duration": 5, "goal_name": "Retirement"}, {"amount": 0, "duration": 2, "goal_name": "Shopping"}, {"amount": 0, "duration": 2, "goal_name": "Travel"}, {"amount": 12, "duration": 3, "goal_name": "Wedding"}
]
}
    ''';
    http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);

    return json.decode(response.body);

    /*Response request;
    try {
      request = await Requests.get(
        url + '/savings_goal_display',
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
        // TODO: when having true ssl certificate, change verify to true.
        // verify: false,
        timeoutSeconds: 20,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return {"result": "Connection Error: $e"};
    }
    if (!request.hasError) {
      try {
        return request.json() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      } catch (e) {
        return {"result": "$e"};
      }
    } else {
      return {"result": "Unknown Request Error"};
    }*/
  }

  Future<List<GoalsModel>> renewDataForView() async {
    var dic = await _getGoals();
    Payload payload;
    if (dic != null) {
      payload = Payload.fromJson(dic);
    }
    // print(goals);
    return payload.savingsGoalsDic;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GoalViewServices goalViewServices = GoalViewServices();

  Future<List<GoalsModel>> _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = goalViewServices.renewDataForView();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<GoalsModel>> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                              elevation: 6.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 6.0,
                                    bottom: 6.0,
                                    left: 8.0,
                                    right: 8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data[index].totalAmount
                                          .toString(),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```